# getting a random animation totally random

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, animation, random

I have created a random fishes animation but at some point (about 10sec) from the beginning, my fishes Cling to the right, i want them to keep moving in random all over the area, any idea?

here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/832Fx/1/

jquery code:

```
$.fn.rotate = function (degrees) {
    var self = $(this);
    self.transition({
        rotateY: degrees + 'deg'
    }, 5000);
};

var animeVars = {
    maxPixelsPerSecond: 50,
    minPixelsPerSecond: 10,
    topMargin: 0,
    bottomMargin: 400,
    leftMargin: 0,
    rightMargin: 400
};

function topFlip(obj) {
    var speed = $(obj).data('speed') ? (1 / parseFloat($(obj).data('speed'))) * 1000000 : 300;
    $(obj).find('.top_fin, .top_fins').transition({
        rotate: '+=25deg',
        x: '+=10'
    }, speed, function () {
        $(obj).find('.top_fin, .top_fins').transition({
            rotate: '-=25deg',
            x: '-=10'
        }, speed, function () {
            topFlip(obj);
        });
    });
}

function tailFlip(obj) {
    var speed = $(obj).data('speed') ? (1 / parseFloat($(obj).data('speed'))) * 1000000 : 300;
    $(obj).find('.tail_fin, .tail_fins').transition({
        rotateX: '-=25deg'
    }, speed, function () {
        $(obj).find('.tail_fin, .tail_fins').transition({
            rotateX: '+=25deg'
        }, speed, function () {
            tailFlip(obj);
        });
    });
}

function animateFish(obj) {
    var heading = $(obj).data('heading');
    if (!heading) heading = 'left';
    var rotation = 0;
    var currentCoords = {
        top: parseInt($(obj).css('top').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''), 10),
        left: parseInt($(obj).css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''), 10)
    };
    var newCoords = {
        top: Math.random() * (animeVars.topMargin - animeVars.bottomMargin + 1) + animeVars.bottomMargin,
        left: Math.random() * (animeVars.leftMargin - animeVars.rightMargin + 1) + animeVars.rightMargin
    };
    if (currentCoords.left < newCoords.left && heading != 'right') {
        $(obj).rotate(180);
        $(obj).data('heading', 'right');
        console.log('swimming right');
    } else if (currentCoords.left > newCoords.left && heading != 'left') {
        $(obj).rotate(0);
        $(obj).data('heading', 'left');
        console.log('swimming left');
    }

    var totalMovement = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(currentCoords.left - newCoords.left, 2) + Math.pow(currentCoords.top - newCoords.top, 2));
    console.log('Total pixels to move: ' + totalMovement);
    var pps = Math.floor(Math.random() * (animeVars.maxPixelsPerSecond - animeVars.maxPixelsPerSecond)) + animeVars.maxPixelsPerSecond;
    var speed = totalMovement / pps * 1000;

    $(obj).data('speed', speed);
    $(obj).animate({
        top: newCoords.top,
        left: newCoords.left
    }, speed, function () {
        animateFish(obj);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.loop ').each(function () {
        animateFish(this);
        topFlip(this);
        tailFlip(this);
    });

});
```

Comment: Works fine for me.. going totally random even after 10 seconds.

Comment: @putvande except they are going to the left area and stay there

Comment: Your fish are stuck between `0px` and `400px` because your random algorithm set their location between `leftMargin` and `rightMargin` (the name of these variables is pretty inaccurate though, it should just be `left` and `right`, they are not margins but bounds).

Comment: @BaliBalo so what should i do?

Comment: @alonblack Either change `marginRight` value to the window width (when it resizes) or change your algorithm to set the fish location between `marginLeft` and the window width minus `marginRight`

Comment: @BaliBalo I'm really lost can you show me more specific where to change

Comment: @Jacques Snyman can you pleas help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would fix this: http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/832Fx/2/

I just added

```
var $wnd = $(window);
$wnd.resize(function() {
    animeVars.rightMargin = $wnd.width();
    animeVars.bottomMargin = $wnd.height();
}).resize();
```

at the end of your code, and changed the algorithm a bit to take in account fishes size:

```
var w = $(obj).width();
var h = $(obj).height();
var newCoords = {
    top: Math.random() * (animeVars.topMargin - animeVars.bottomMargin + h + 1) + animeVars.bottomMargin - h,
    left: Math.random() * (animeVars.leftMargin - animeVars.rightMargin + w + 1) + animeVars.rightMargin - w
};
```

However, please note that many optimizations could be done, like caching jQuery objects in variables rather than calling the `$` function every time.

Comment: it's almost perfect! thanks so much, as u see here:http://jsfiddle.net/832Fx/3/ the fishes now pass the bottom of the fishtanks, i didn't succeed to fix that can u help last time plz?

Comment: Position computed is the top of the fish. You have to take the height of the fish in account. Do it with `var h = $(obj).height();`  and then in `newCoords`: `top: Math.random() * (animeVars.topMargin - animeVars.bottomMargin + h + 1) + animeVars.bottomMargin - h` (just like in my answer)

Comment: you mean i should creat another one or use the existing code?

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/832Fx/4/. You should do the same with the width to prevent the fishes passing the right border of the fishtank